# Как спарсить данные с одинаковым классом id ,но с разным названием?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup

Не судите строго,я новичок и многого не знаю.(Изображение прикрепил) Дан класс "bigline" в нем есть "id" записи к которой мне надо обратиться ,но я не знаю как! Если я прошу найти все на "li" то он выдает мне ошибку так ,как на сайте полно и других элементов так же с "li".Сам сайт: [https://bloknot-astrakhan.ru/]  Заранее спасибо!

[image: Вот сам код сайта]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сначала надо найти *bigline*, т.е. сделать изначальную фильтрацию, сохранить найденное в переменную. А затем можно обращаться ко всем элементам `<li>` внутри отфильтрованных данных, тогда ничего лишнего не прилетит.

```python
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

r = requests.get('https://bloknot-astrakhan.ru/')
soup = BS(r.content, 'lxml')

news = soup.find("ul", {"class": "bigline"})
for article in news.find_all('li'):
    print(article.get('id'))
```

###### Вывод:

```
bx_3218110189_1633348
bx_3218110189_1633344
bx_3218110189_1633298
bx_3218110189_1633278
bx_3218110189_1633277
bx_3218110189_1633245
bx_3218110189_1633238
bx_3218110189_1633230
bx_3218110189_1633223
bx_3218110189_1633212
```

Comment: А можно ли это сделать на html, а не lxml?

Comment: Можно. А чем вам `lxml` не угодил? Можете просто эту опцию не передавать, по дефолту html будет.

Comment: Проблема не в самом lxml , просто при изменении на lxml у меня другие функции не работают и выдает ошибки

Comment: Понятно. [Здесь](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) список доступных парсеров, пробуйте с каким работать будет. `html5lib` самый надёжный, но и самый медленный.